# Call Salesforce REST API from Cordova app

Tags: rest, cordova, jquery-mobile, salesforce, force.com

We've built a force.com app and developed some Restful APIs to be consumed by a Cordova/PhoneGap mobile app. What we exactly need is that we want the mobile app to call the Salesforce Rest APIs without having to "**manually**" login. This means the credentials of Salesforce should be hardcoded into the Cordova/PhoneGap mobile app and Oauth authentication will happen behind the scene.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if provider (salesforce here) has authorization end point or token end point which does not open dialog to key-in user credential, like response_type=token end point or password grant type. Basically which are used for REST API calls.
But this approach is **not advisible**. If anyone decompiles your binary, would easily get the salesforce credential.